# How to setInputMask or setValidator to Qlineedit for Date format?

Tags: python-3.x, validation, pyqt5, qlineedit, input-mask

I tried below code:

```
self.lineEdit.setInputMask("0000-00-00")
```

Its sets the mask, But i want to use the format as "year-month-day" and the month should be have the range as 1 - 12 and day should be the range as 1 - 31.
For example "2019-12-31" not as "2019-33-60"
Is it possible? How to do?

Comment: Why can't you use a [QDateEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdateedit.html)?

Comment: Why Because I want to use the date as optional. If I use Qdate , it will become as mandatory i think. Some times the date field should be null.

Comment: I'd suggest you to consider using a QDateEdit anyway (you can clear the text by accessing it's [`lineEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#lineEdit) and call `setText('')`). Anyway, the number range you are referring to would not be correct: you cannot only use 1-31 range for day numbers (consider leap years), string dates *must* be validated correctly.